# The security of cyclic affine key schedules

Tags: symmetric, key-schedule

Suppose that $k$ is the key for a block cipher. I am interested in the security of key schedules of the form $(k_0,\dots,k_n)$ where $k=k_0$ and $k_{j+1}=A_jk_j+b_j$ where each $A_j$ is some constant invertible matrix and $b_j$ is a constant vector and where $k_0=k_n$ so that the final round key is the original key. In particular, we would have $A_{n-1}\dots A_0=I$. We may call these key schedules affine cyclic key schedules.

**Motivation:** Landauer's limit states that it costs $k\cdot T\cdot\ln(2)$ energy in order to delete a bit of information where $k$ is Boltzmann's constant, and $T$ is the temperature. But in order to overcome thermal noise, one should expect to spend about $100\cdot k\cdot T$ energy per bit deletion in order to overcome thermal noise in an ideal setting regardless of the hardware one uses [3] (and in practice, one needs to spend much more energy per bit deletion). Reversible computing is the art of computing while deleting little information in order to save the energy that one is required to spend according to Landauer's principle. One could also say that reversible computing is the art of computing where all the components of the computation are bijective. See [4] for more information about reversible computing. While we do not have fully functional energy efficient reversible hardware yet, this is probably a good time to start designing more algorithms for reversible computation. Since symmetric encryption functions are always invertible, it makes sense to design, evaluate, and standardize these symmetric encryption functions for efficiency on reversible hardware. Block ciphers that run on reversible hardware will also be more secure against side-channel attacks such as power attacks [2], so reversible block ciphers will be more secure and efficient than block ciphers that are not designed for reversible hardware. But irreversible block ciphers that run on reversible hardware will need to use uncomputation, but the process of uncomputation will not only be inefficient but it seems like it will give more opportunities to launch side-channel attacks.

If we designed a key scheduling algorithm for reversibility and so that we do not have to keep the entire expanded key in memory, we would want to design the key schedule so that the final round key is the same as the initial round key. And in an irreversible context, it will be more efficient for the final round key to be the same as the initial round key so that one does not have to keep both the round key (or fully expanded key) and the unexpanded key in memory. One way to do this is to use a key schedule of the form $(k_0,\dots,k_{m-1},k_m,k_{m-1},\dots,k_0)$ or $(k_0,\dots,k_{m-1},k_m,k_m,k_{m-1},\dots,k_0)$, but in this case, one will need to reuse the round keys multiple times. If we wanted to make a reversible key schedule without needing to reuse the round keys while rewinding them, then one will probably need to use an affine key schedule.

What are some security weaknesses (beyond simply linearity) for block ciphers with a cyclic affine key schedule? I am looking for security weaknesses for cyclic affine key schedules that are designed to run on energy efficient and side channel attack resistant reversible hardware. In particular, I am interested in security weaknesses for Example 1 and Example 2 below.

**Examples:** There are several ways that I can think of of attaining matrices $A_{0},\dots,A_{n-1}$ with $A_{n-1}\dots A_0=I$. There are probably other ways of attaining this property as well.

Example 0: If $A_{n-1}\dots A_0=I$ and $B_{n-1}\dots B_0=I$, then $(A_{n-1}\otimes B_{n-1})\dots(A_0\otimes B_0)=I$ as well.

Example 1: Suppose that $K$ is a finite field and $f(x),g(x)$ are polynomials over $K$. Suppose that $f(x)g(x)+1=f_{n-1}(x)\dots f_0(x)$, then $f_{n-1}(x)\dots f_0(x)+\langle f(x)\rangle=1+\langle f(x)\rangle$, and multiplication by $f_j(x)$ is a $K$-linear operation over the ring $K[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$. One multiplies by $f_j(x)$ in $K[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$ differently than one divides by $f_j(x)$, but, for optimal reversibility, both multiplication and division should be computed the same way using the same reversible circuit.

Example 2: Reversible linear cellular automata over finite abelian groups [tend to have low periods](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283302/why-do-some-linear-cellular-automata-over-z-2-on-the-torus-have-small-order). But these linear cellular automata have a lot of symmetry which may make these cellular automata easy to analyze but they may present a cryptographic weakness. Perhaps an answerer may be able to pinpoint a specific cryptographic weakness with this approach.

[2]: https://arxiv.org/ftp/cs/papers/0610/0610089.pdf Reversible Logic to
Cryptographic Hardware: A New Paradigm. Himanshu Thapliyal, Mark Zwolinski

[3]: [https://web1.eng.famu.fsu.edu/~mpf/ip1-Frank.pdf](https://web1.eng.famu.fsu.edu/%7Empf/ip1-Frank.pdf) Introduction to Reversible Computing: Motivation, Progress, and Challenges CF '05: Proceedings of the 2nd conference on Computing frontiers May 2005 Pages 385–390

[4]: Perumalla, K.S. (2013). Introduction to Reversible Computing (1st ed.). Chapman and Hall/CRC. https://doi.org/10.1201/b15719

Comment: In my opinion designing a cipher to be efficient for reverse computability is a lofty design goal. However, I'm also very much of opinion that any statement regarding side channel protection should come with sufficient proof. Or do you assume that we can get an energy equilibrium using reverse computing? For me there are too many assumptions stated as fact in your question.

Comment: It is difficult to see how you could say anything useful (and nontrivial) about the security of a key schedule apart from the details of the rest of the cipher...